# Send data to remote server using jsonp

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jsonp

Here is My code:
server A

```
$(function() {

        var diffDomainUrl = 'http://domain_B.com/analtyics/cookie.php?jsoncallback=mycallback';

    $('.idlink').on('click', function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: diffDomainUrl,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            data: {},
            success: function (data, textStatus) {
                console.log(textStatus);
                console.log(data);
            },
            jsonpCallback: 'mycallback'
        });
    });

});
```

and server B

```
<?php
$_GET['jsoncallback'];
if(isset($_GET['jsoncallback']))
{
setcookie("T_LNG",$_GET['jsoncallback'],strtotime('+30 days'));

echo $_COOKIE['T_LNG']."Welcome";
} ?>
```

in this code i m not getting anything. i don't know whthere its working or not or my method is wrong.

Comment: your url contain call back already so dont set that in ajax remove and try remove this `jsonpCallback: 'mycallback'`

Comment: your correct, it works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your url contain call back already so dont set that in ajax remove and try remove this `jsonpCallback: 'mycallback'`

Try this

```
$(function() {

        var diffDomainUrl = 'http://domain_B.com/analtyics/cookie.php?jsoncallback=mycallback';

    $('.idlink').on('click', function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: diffDomainUrl,
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            data: {},
            success: function (data, textStatus) {
                console.log(textStatus);
                console.log(data);
            }

        });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1):

change 
`$_GET['jsoncallback'];`
to

```
$_GET['callback'];
```

Answer (score 0):

As per jQuery Docs

```
 "jsonp": Loads in a JSON block using JSONP. Adds an extra "?callback=?" to the end of 
your URL to specify the callback. Disables caching by appending a query string parameter,  "_=[TIMESTAMP]", to the URL unless the cache option is set to true.
```

Try

```
$(function() {

        var diffDomainUrl = 'http://domain_B.com/analtyics/cookie.php?callback=?';

    $('.idlink').on('click', function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: diffDomainUrl,
            type: "POST",//if not specified get is the default
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            data: {}, //send data to server as key value pair if any eg {id:20}
            jsonpCallback: 'mycallback'
        });
    });

});
```

And your callback function

```
 function mycallback(responseJSON){
       ........
    }
```